# Changing value of array at one index location changes value at other locations as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to change the value of a 2D array at index location [0][0], however the value at [1][0] gets changed as well. A different approach yields the correct value change at [0][0] without affecting any other value. Unable to understand the difference between the 2 methods.

Method 1:

```
function abc1(){

    var dimArr=[2,3];
    var arr=[];
    var val=0;
    for (var i=dimArr.length-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
     arr = [];
     for(var k=0; k<dimArr[i]; k++)
     arr.push(val);

     val = arr;

   }    
   return arr;
}
```

Method 2:

```
function abc2(){

    var outterArray = [];

    for(var i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        var innerArray = [];
        for(var j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            innerArray.push(0);
        }
        outterArray.push(innerArray);
    }

    return outterArray;
}
```

When I run the script:

```
var d2= abc1();

d2[0][0]='a';

console.log(d2);

var d3= abc2();

d3[0][0]='a';

console.log(d3);
```

The variable d2 logs:

```
[["a", 0, 0], ["a", 0, 0]]
```

The variable d3 logs:

```
[["a", 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the purpose of "val" in abc1?

Comment: Your first one just put the same `val` to `arr`, when its `array`, it means you put the 2 reference to that `array` into `arr`, so when you changed the first ones value, the second also reflect the change, you can use `d2[0] === d2[1]` to see that they're the same.

Comment: And in `abc2`, in each `i` iteration, you use `var innerArray = [];` to create a new array, so changes to one would not reflect on another.

Comment: @fuyushimoya By that logic, if the innerArray is initialized outside the for loop, it should show similar result as the first method but it doesn't.

Comment: No it should not. If you put it outside, you just first push 3 `0` to it, then put it to outerarray, then put another 3 `0`, and put to outer array again, then you should get `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`. And in this case, `d3[0][0] = 'a'` will cause `d3[1][0]` becomes `a`, similar to first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words:

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = a;

// Only change in array a 
a[0] = 10;    
// will give you [10, 2, 3] as you set b= a so its points to same address which is a its not a copy of the array its pointing to same array
console.log(b);
```

if you checked this Question [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) copy array by default is by reference `a` is holding a refrence to the array and when you say `b=a` so you allow `b` to point to same location `a` is pointing to, BUT if you need to copy array by value you will need to do as poiniting in the `Post` `b = a.slice();`

And that what happeaned in `function abc1()` `val` pushed to `arr` and in second loop you pushed `val` again which is still pointing to same array so what you have is [pointer to array1, pointer to array1] so its exactly same array, so when you change value `[0][0]` it will change the value and the 2 pointer which is pointing to the same array will show you same result.

and as you can see in your `function abc2()` it say `var innerArray = [];` so you created a new refrence to a new array and not pointing to the old `innerArray` array.